# TypeError: Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Just a simple problem.

I want to assign a `HTMLMediaElement` method to variable.

```
// html part
<video id="player" ... />

// js part
const video = document.querySelector('#player')
const play = video.play

video.play() // works!

play() // error!

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': Illegal invocation
```

anyone knows why this error happened?

Comment: I think you need to bind `this` to `video`? --- Yep, binding works, `play = play.bind(video)`

Comment: This question feels like it's a duplicate... but I can't find a dupe target.

Comment: if you don't find previous question. You can post the answer to answer block.

Comment: But I just wonder if any functional programming way solve it without bind?

Comment: Functional programming way? `Bind` is functional programming...

Comment: My bad! What I mean is without `this` :P

Comment: I don't think there is such a way (afaik). The underlying implementation of the native DOM play method requires a `this` value.

Comment: OK, I got it. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The native DOM implementation of `HTMLMediaElement.play` requires `this` to be bound to an `HTMLMediaElement`.

`video.play()` works because the `this` value is bound to `video`.
`play()` doesn't work because the `this` value is now bound to something else (maybe `window`?).

You can either call it using:

```js
const video = document.querySelector('#video');
play = video.play;

play.call(video);
```

```html
<video id="video" src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" controls>
```

or "save it for later" using bind:

```js
const video = document.querySelector('#video');
play = video.play.bind(video);

play();
```

```html
<video id="video" src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" controls>
```

Comment: I'd appreciate someone commenting/editing this answer as to what the value of `this` is when `play` is invoked without being bound to `video`.

Comment: To reply to my own comment... it is most likely `undefined`.